# CS0649 warning on private static field

Tags: c#, static, field, warnings, private

I'm getting the following warning:

> Warning CS0649    Field 'TemplateManager.Templates' is never assigned to,
>   and will always have its default value null

The relevant code is as follows:

```
public static class TemplateManager
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, Stream> Templates;
        public static List<string> TemplateNames { get; private set; }

        static TemplateManager()
        {
            Templates = new Dictionary<string, Stream>();
            TemplateNames = new List<string>();
        }
```

It seems to me that I am assigning a value to it. Is this a bug or am I just missing something important? Is it related to the fact that the class and/or field are static?

Comment: Are you sure you've typed it correctly? I'm not getting any error in my Visual Studio. In fact you could remove the initialization and there'll still be no syntax error - static variables need not be assigned at all..

Comment: I tried to reproduce this and I do not get the error, it is most likely an issue with VS not updating the warnings for some reason, this happens from time to time. Just compile or restart VS and it should go away.

Comment: If you move the initialization to the field itself (instead of in the constructor), do you still get the error?

Comment: It seems like cleaning and rebuilding the project solved it. Thanks for the help! Had tried just recompiling and restarting already with no luck, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by cleaning and rebuilding my project.

Answer (score -3):

The reason for this is probably because you have set as private. This could mean you cannot access the set function so it will never be updated from being null. Remove the private before set and try it.

[Update]
Yeah my bad I completely misread that.

Comment: That is not what `private` does.